# boolean mask if timestamp from a df is with two time points from second df - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two distinct data frames. Both contain timestamps and corresponding values. I'm aiming to subset or provide boolean indexing where the time from one df falls within two timepoints from a second df.

`df` contains names and start/end times. I want to use this info for `df2`. So where the same name is present (`John`), I want to provide a boolean index if `Time` falls within `Start Time` and `End Time`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
               'Start Time' : ['2010-03-20 09:27:00','2010-03-20 10:15:00','2010-03-20 11:10:38','2010-03-20 11:32:15','2010-03-20 11:45:38'],
               'End Time' : ['2010-03-20 09:40:00','2010-03-20 10:32:15','2010-03-20 11:35:38','2010-03-20 11:38:15','2010-03-20 11:50:38'],
               "Name":['John', 'Brian', 'Suni', 'Gary', 'Li'],
               "Occ":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],                   
               })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
               'Time' : ['2010-03-20 09:27:28','2010-03-20 09:29:15','2010-03-20 09:30:38','2010-03-20 09:32:15','2010-03-20 09:38:38',
                         '2010-03-20 10:15:08','2010-03-20 10:16:36','2010-03-20 10:30:12','2010-03-20 10:31:08','2010-03-20 10:32:48'],
               'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 
                       'John', 'John', 'Li', 'Li', 'Li'],
               })

df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'])

df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])

mask1 = (df2['Time'] > df['Start Time']) & (df2['Time'] < df['End Time'])

    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I/O: Use mask to find rows that meet criteria and subset df2.

```
True
True
True
True
True  
False
False
False
False
False

                 Time  Name
0 2010-03-20 09:27:28  John
1 2010-03-20 09:29:15  John
2 2010-03-20 09:30:38  John
3 2010-03-20 09:32:15  John
4 2010-03-20 09:38:38  John
```

Edit 2:

Is it possible to assign values from `df` to `df2` where same conditions are met?

For ex, df is the same except for an additional col:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
               'Start Time' : ['2010-03-20 09:27:00','2010-03-20 10:15:00','2010-03-20 11:10:38','2010-03-20 11:32:15','2010-03-20 11:45:38'],
               'End Time' : ['2010-03-20 09:40:00','2010-03-20 10:32:15','2010-03-20 11:35:38','2010-03-20 11:38:15','2010-03-20 11:50:38'],
               "Name":['John', 'Brian', 'Suni', 'John', 'Li'], 
               "Occ":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
               })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
               'Time' : ['2010-03-20 09:27:28','2010-03-20 09:29:15','2010-03-20 09:30:38','2010-03-20 09:32:15','2010-03-20 09:38:38',
                         '2010-03-20 11:11:08','2010-03-20 11:16:36','2010-03-20 11:30:12','2010-03-20 11:31:08','2010-03-20 11:32:48',
                         ],
               'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John',  
                       'Suni', 'Suni', 'Li', 'John', 'John', 
                       ],
               "desc":[6, 6, 6, np.nan, np.nan, 
                       89, 89, np.nan, 2, 2
                       ], 
               })
```

Could we use the same function but pass `Occ` to `df2` for the relevant rows.

I/O:

```
                  Time  Name  desc    msk  Occ
0  2010-03-20 09:27:28  John   6.0   True  1.0
1  2010-03-20 09:29:15  John   6.0   True  1.0
2  2010-03-20 09:30:38  John   6.0   True  1.0
3  2010-03-20 09:32:15  John   NaN   True  1.0
4  2010-03-20 09:38:38  John   NaN   True  1.0
5  2010-03-20 11:11:08  Suni  89.0   True  3.0
6  2010-03-20 11:16:36  Suni  89.0   True  3.0
7  2010-03-20 11:30:12    Li   NaN  False  NaN
8  2010-03-20 11:31:08  John   2.0  False  NaN
9  2010-03-20 11:32:48  John   2.0   True  4.0
```

Comment: what is your desired output, exactly?  reduce the number of rows of df2 and provide exact desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your dataframes as first approach. You need to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to preserve the `df2` index:

```
idx = (df2.reset_index().merge(df, on='Name')
          .loc[lambda x:x['Time'].between(x['Start Time'], x['End Time']), 'index'])
msk = df2.index.isin(idx)
```

You have to re

Output:

```
>>> msk
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False])

>>> pd.Series(msk, index=df2.index)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Maybe [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) can be better?

```
idx = (pd.merge_asof(df2.reset_index().sort_values('Time'), 
                     df.sort_values('Start Time'),
                     left_on='Time', right_on='Start Time', by='Name')
         .loc[lambda x:x['Time'].between(x['Start Time'], x['End Time']), 'index'])
msk = df2.index.isin(idx)
```

**Edit 2**

You can do:

```
cx = (df2.reset_index().merge(df, on='Name')
         .loc[lambda x:x['Time'].between(x['Start Time'], x['End Time'])]
         .set_index('index').rename_axis(None))

df2['mask'] = df2.index.isin(cx.index)
df2['Occ'] = cx['Occ']
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
                 Time  Name  desc   mask  Occ
0 2010-03-20 09:27:28  John   6.0   True  1.0
1 2010-03-20 09:29:15  John   6.0   True  1.0
2 2010-03-20 09:30:38  John   6.0   True  1.0
3 2010-03-20 09:32:15  John   NaN   True  1.0
4 2010-03-20 09:38:38  John   NaN   True  1.0
5 2010-03-20 11:11:08  Suni  89.0   True  3.0
6 2010-03-20 11:16:36  Suni  89.0   True  3.0
7 2010-03-20 11:30:12    Li   NaN  False  NaN
8 2010-03-20 11:31:08  John   2.0  False  NaN
9 2010-03-20 11:32:48  John   2.0   True  4.0
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. A quick one. Is it possible to assign values from a col in `df` to `df2`? Or will it have to be a separate function? I've edited to include a working example.

Comment: @Chopin. I updated my answer according your comment. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to group all rows in `df2` which falls into `df` as well as `df2` meets following criteria:

- Name should be the same, or
- Time need to be fall within `df`'s time range

This code is also fixed the time of `df2` from `2010` to `2021`, for grouping method I will simply use apply each row of `df2` into looping of each `df`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
               'Start Time' : ['2021-03-20 09:27:00','2021-03-20 10:15:00','2021-03-20 11:10:38','2021-03-20 11:32:15','2021-03-20 11:45:38'],
               'End Time' : ['2021-03-20 09:40:00','2021-03-20 10:32:15','2021-03-20 11:35:38','2021-03-20 11:38:15','2021-03-20 11:50:38'],
               "Name":['John', 'Brian', 'Suni', 'Gary', 'Li'], 
               })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
               'Time' : ['2021-03-20 09:27:28','2021-03-20 09:29:15','2021-03-20 09:30:38','2021-03-20 09:32:15','2021-03-20 09:38:38',
                         '2021-03-20 10:15:08','2021-03-20 10:16:36','2021-03-20 10:30:12','2021-03-20 10:31:08','2021-03-20 10:32:48',
                         ],
               'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 
                       'John', 'John', 'Li', 'Li', 'Li', 
                       ],
               })

df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'])
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time'])

def find_group(time):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['Start Time'] <= time <= row['End Time']:
            return str(row['Name'])
    return None

# Apply the function to create a new column 'Group' in df2
df2['Group'] = df2['Time'].apply(lambda x: find_group(pd.to_datetime(x)))
df2['Bool'] = df2['Group'] == df2['Name']
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
                 Time  Name  Group   Bool
0 2021-03-20 09:27:28  John   John   True
1 2021-03-20 09:29:15  John   John   True
2 2021-03-20 09:30:38  John   John   True
3 2021-03-20 09:32:15  John   John   True
4 2021-03-20 09:38:38  John   John   True
5 2021-03-20 10:15:08  John  Brian  False
6 2021-03-20 10:16:36  John  Brian  False
7 2021-03-20 10:30:12    Li  Brian  False
8 2021-03-20 10:31:08    Li  Brian  False
9 2021-03-20 10:32:48    Li   None  False
```

Comment: Don't do that! At least, use `groupby` to avoid to compare times for two different names which is useless.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

merge & use pipe(with between)

```
df2.merge(df, how='left')\
   .pipe(lambda x: x['Time'].between(x['Start Time'], x['End Time']))
```